# Chartboost Delegate Integration Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, chartboost

I just upgraded to Chartboost SDK 5.0. It works fine and ads display but for some reason I am getting this warning:

```
 Chartboost Integration Warning: startWithAppId:appSignature:delegate must be called before +[Chartboost cacheInterstitial:]
```

Any idea why? I'm calling `startWithAppId` in my AppDelegate under `-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:` and then I just cache the interstitials in a different class with `[Chartboost  cacheInterstitial:CBLocationMainMenu];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning indicates that in your application startup sequence the

`[Chartboost  cacheInterstitial...]`

call executed before you start the Chartboost session with

`[Chartboost startWithAppId...]`.

[As the developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html) tells the iOS launch sequence has the following order:

1. application: willFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2. application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
3. applicationDidBecomeActive

So as the current [Chartboost integration help](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201220095-iOS-Integration#quickstart) suggests the `[Chartboost startWithAppId..]` call should go into the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method then the caching call.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the code to initialize Chartboost in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an "answer" but the easiest way to avoid that, is simply by putting the code for the "interstital cache" just after the other line on your AppDelegate. It will also help your app having more time to get the Ad.